# Simple loop task

Tags: python, loops

I am trying create an application that will loop between 1 and 100 and return the squared value and if the squared value is greater than 200 it should break and list the values.
my attempt is as follows

```
user = float(input("Number"))
for i in range(1,int(user)):
    print(i,i**2)
    if i**2 > 200:
        break

Output:
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
10 100
11 121
12 144
13 169
14 196
15 225
```

if `15**2 >=200` why is it included in the list should it not stop when i=14

Comment: if you don't want to print a number whose square is larger than 200, then change your check to `if (i+1)**2 > 200:`

Comment: You only check the condition *after* printing. That means you can't undo having printed the value for ``i==15``.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is printed because you placed the print statement before the break statement. When `i = 15`, it first prints `15` and `225`. After printing, it evaluates that `225 > 200` and ends the loop. To prevent this, try the following:

```py
user = float(input("Number"))
for i in range(1,int(user)):
    if i**2 > 200:
        break
    print(i,i**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you put the

```
print(i, i**2)
```

before the if condition

```
if i**2 > 200
```

Try this

```
user = float(input("Number"))
for i in range(1,int(user)):
    if i**2 > 200:
        break
    print(i,i**2)
```